# Picture of Rav Elchonon Wasserman on boat

Tags: rabbis

Heard in a shiur that there’s a picture of Rav Elchonon Wasserman on a ship looking out to the sea facing Europe, after leaving America and going to Europe knowing that Hitler was in power and he would most likely die. And it’s apparently an ominous photo. I couldn’t find it on google, can anyone help me find the picture?

Comment: https://mishpacha.com/the-eternal-flame/

Comment: @shmosel thank you

Comment: This question doesn't seem to me to be on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here: https://mishpacha.com/the-eternal-flame/

> [image: Rav Elchonon Wasserman]
>
> *“I’m a soldier, I have to go to the front.” Rav Elchonon on the deck of the ship returning to Europe in March 1939*
>
> ...
>
> In March of 1939, Rav Elchonon declared that he was returning to
> Europe. His American confidants begged him to stay, but he refused. “I
> don’t have only three sons,” he said, “I have hundreds — the yeshivah
> bochurim. How can I leave them?” When asked how he could justify
> returning to a potential powder keg, Rav Elchonon answered
> unequivocally, “I am a soldier; I have to go to the front.”